# Is it correct to use "In that" at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: phrases

Is it correct to start a sentence using "in that"? I had a professor who would do it all the time so I started using it in papers, today someone told me it is not a complete sentence on the basis of starting the sentence with "in that". Obviously this sentence was an explanation following a statement made in the previous.

Example:

> The emphasis by both Le Roy and Erasmus on the recovery of language
>   and art as “illuminating” suggests the time before was dark and alien.
>   In that both texts possess an ominous vision of the future, which
>   reveals an anxiety surrounding any deviation from the dictated
>   Renaissance values.

Comment: Please give an example of a whole sentence that you find questionable. It is certainly possible to construct sentences that begin with "In that" we need further and better particulars before we can help you here.

Comment: In that you ask a question of English usage, this is a valid post — but the example you provide doesn't meet this structure: there's no principle clause. Replace "which" with "this" and it's both meaningful and grammatical.

Comment: "In that" is being used in roughly the same sense as "given that".

Comment: @chappo Maybe "they reveal" rather than "this reveals"? In that both texts do x, they reveal y.

Comment: @remarkl I'd initially thought yes, your suggestion is right, but I've reconsidered. I agree with Hot Licks that *in that* = *given that* (in this context at least), and therefore *this* refers to the "given fact". Alternatively, *this* means the entire preceding clause. Your suggestion is **also correct** but has a different semantic interpretation: the *texts* reveal an anxiety, rather than *the possession of an ominous vision* revealing that anxiety. Subtle but important difference.

Comment: @chappo -  I don't believe "in that" is equivalent to "given." I read "in that" as an adverbial prepositional phrase, as in "The two horses differ *in that* the black one is four inches taller than the white one."  The phrase modifies "differ" by telling us *how* the horses differ.  *Mutatis mutandis* (don't you *love* Latin?), the "In that" phrase tells us *how* the texts reveal anxiety.

Comment: The use of *which* in the second sentence after the comma is wrong. Either what comes after the comma should be a question or you should replace *which* with something like *this*, *it*, or *they*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my understanding, "In that..." roughly corresponds to "given that..." or "insofar as..."

All of these phrases could begin a sentence, but the sentence would need a clause with a main verb. Ex: "In that both texts possess an ominous vision, **they** **are** similar." In your example, there is no main verb, so it isn't a complete sentence.

I would also note: if you deleted the "in that" from your example sentence, the sentence would stand on its own, and (in my opinion) be stronger.